# Retrieve category description when using wp gridbuilder

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

How to retrieve the category description when using a filter like wp Gridbuilder?

I created a sort filter for the categories, when clicking on a category the url looks something like this: domain.com/music/?_categories=8-bit-chiptune

Normally using `<?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>` would work on the archive category page but whe using a filter there is no category page.

Thanks

Comment: Please, share your full code. It would be great easily fix your problem.

Comment: Hi, unfortunally I don't have a code beside using <?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code & process as your need.

```
<?php
    
    $cat_slug = $_GET['_categories'];

    $idObj = get_category_by_slug( $cat_slug );
 
    if ( $idObj instanceof WP_Term ) {
        echo $id = $idObj->description;
    }
```

Feel free to query question about it.

Comment: Hi,

Unfortunally it is not working.
I tried on on our staging website here: 
http://dev.dl-sounds.com/royalty-free/?_categories=hypnosis-relaxation

As you can see the category hypnosis-relaxation is selected in the filter. I used your code in a snippet and should appear left of the sorter Product Order.

Thanks

Comment: Where you can display the category description?

Comment: You mean where I add the description? In admin Download categories. I forgot to mention we use Easy digital downloads. The url when editing looks like this 

'wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=download_category&post_type=download'